# How to iterate HTML code with foreach and make animation?

Tags: c#, html, css, blazor

There is a certain code:

```
<div class="button-group">
    <button class="button"></button>
    <button class="button"></button>
    <button class="button"></button>
    <button class="button"></button>
    <button class="button"></button>
    <button class="button"></button>
</div>
```

It is necessary to make an animation so that the buttons appear by opacity one after the other

The problem is that I can't "catch on" to class button-group.
Therefore, this iteration does not work: (because it enumerates char)

```
@foreach (var i in "button-group")
{
    @i
}
```

I tried to do it in Stylus, but there you need to specify the number of "child", so it's not that (or maybe there is a solution, but due to low experience I did not see such functionality).

Comment: Sounds like a job for some JavaScript... perhaps start with the initial button and then use JS to either swap it with the next button or change the class depending on how your animation works...

Comment: You can use JS method getElementsByClassName

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answers.
As a result, I answer my question - no, custom animation in C# is currently impossible to implement, only JS.

Code in JS to solve the problem:

```
const btn1 = document.querySelectorAll(".button");

btn1.forEach((btn1,number) => {
    btn1.style.animationDelay = (number/20 + "s");
});
```

CSS:

```
.button {
  animation: fade .1s linear forwards;
  opacity: 0;
}

@keyframes fade {
 0% {
 opacity: 0;
 }
 100% {
 opacity: 1;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This can be done just with CSS.

Each button has an animation which takes it from opacity 0 opacity 1 over a period (0.3s is used in this snippet). Each button's animation is delayed though by an amount that is calculated depending on its child position which is set as a CSS variable --n

```css
.button-group button {
  animation: show 0.3s linear forwards;
  animation-delay: calc((var(--n) - 1) * 0.3s);
  opacity: 0;
}

.button-group button:nth-child(1) {
  --n: 1;
}

.button-group button:nth-child(2) {
  --n: 2;
}

.button-group button:nth-child(3) {
  --n: 3;
}

.button-group button:nth-child(4) {
  --n: 4;
}

.button-group button:nth-child(5) {
  --n: 5;
}

.button-group button:nth-child(6) {
  --n: 6;
}

@keyframes show {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="button-group">
  <button class="button"></button>
  <button class="button"></button>
  <button class="button"></button>
  <button class="button"></button>
  <button class="button"></button>
  <button class="button"></button>
</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly the solution that was in Stylus, and I need to be able to calmly change the number of buttons and the animation worked.

Comment: I gave a Blazor solution for educational value.  But personally, I wouldn't use it. :D

Answer (score 1):

This is @A Haworth's answer, but with the `nth-child` part of the `style` section built dynamically in the `.razor` file rather than hard-set in the `.css` file.

It's not usually recommended to include style in Blazor markup, as it will rebuild every load instead of caching, and I personally wouldn't do it-- but to be honest, it's only a few bytes, and it's really not going to hurt anything.

**buttons.css (link it)**

```
.button-group button {
    animation: show 0.3s linear forwards;
    animation-delay: calc((var(--n) - 1) * 0.3s);
    opacity: 0;
}
@keyframes show {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

**DynamicButtons.razor**

```
<style>
    @((MarkupString)btnString)
</style>
<div class="button-group">
    @for (int i = 1; i <= btnCounter; i++)
    {
        <button>@i</button>
    }
</div>

@code {
    int btnCounter = 20; // This can be whatever you want.
    string btnString = "";

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= btnCounter; i++)
        {
            btnString += ".button-group button:nth-child(" + i + ") { --n: " + i + ";}  ";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Again, I need to iterate foreach existing buttons and assign opacity or delay, but solution is not bad.

Comment: I don't really know what you're trying to do with your buttons, so I can't advise you further than this for now.  If you feel like explaining what the buttons do, or how you create them, I can help you more.